# Phonegap Page Transitions within one page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, cordova

I'm creating a `Phonegap`  iOS and Android application. I've got one `index.html` file where all the pages / tabs are in, each page has it's own div-container. The application is almost finished and now I would like to add a slide-effect when navigating to another page.

My question is, how do I add page transitions within one page that contains several divs?

I have been looking at jQuery Mobile, but this seems to mess up my entire stylesheet. And furthermore, I only need the transitions part of jQuery Mobile, not the entire script. I've found this plugin http://www.fasw.ws/faswwp/non-jquery-page-transitions-lightweight/ but this does not seem to work for one page.

Comment: you have find any solution??

Comment: Better late than never. I've created my own script that uses CSS3 transitions. I recommend using this.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using jQM you should restruct your HTML code so the tags correspond to what the framework needs to make function your transitions. 
But I think your problem is with the Ajax calls, when changing from a page to another.